# Transcribing large datasets into Neo4j via python (Py2neo)

Tags: python, performance, neo4j, py2neo, genome

I've spent the last few weeks trying to load a genomic dataset into Neo4j, using the Scikit Allel library.  I've managed to load all variants for the exomes in a VCF file and all subjects with related phenotype data, I'm now just attempting to create the relationships between the variants and the subjects.  I'm not very experienced in python, and I don't think this question needs a good understanding of either genomics or the Scikit-Allel library, so don't be scared off by that.

The code below works, but incredibly slowly.  I think creating a dataframe, or sets of lists for each subject might be a better way to do this, rather than creating a graph transaction for each element in the `j` for loop, but any advice would be appreciated on how best to do this.  I have looked at including Numba for this as well, but wouldn't know where to start.

This process is creating ~1 new subject per hour, per chromosome out of ~1750 subjects and 23 chromosomes, so it will take a very long time for the current set up to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import math
import allel
import zarr
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, NodeMatcher

zarr_path = '.../chroms.zarr'

callset = zarr.open_group(zarr_path, mode='r')

samples = callset[chrom]['samples']

graph = Graph(user="neo4j", password="password")

chrom_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,'X']

for chrom in chrom_list:


    variants = allel.VariantChunkedTable(callset[chrom]['variants'], names=['AC','AF_AFR', 'AF_AMR', 'AF_ASN', 'AF_EUR', 'AF_MAX', 'CGT', 'CLR', 'CSQ', 'DP', 'DP4', 'ESP_MAF', 'FILTER_LowQual', 'FILTER_MinHWE', 'FILTER_MinVQSLOD', 'FILTER_PASS', 'HWE', 'ICF', 'ID', 'IS', 'PC2', 'PCHI2', 'POS', 'PR', 'QCHI2', 'QUAL', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INDEL', 'SHAPEIT', 'SNP_ID', 'TYPE', 'UGT', 'VQSLOD', 'dbSNPmismatch', 'is_snp', 'numalt'], index='POS')
    pos = variants['POS'][:]
    SNPid = variants['ID'][:]
    ref = variants['REF'][:]
    alt = variants['ALT'][:]
    dp = variants['DP'][:]
    ac = variants['AC'][:]
    vartype = variants['TYPE'][:]
    qual = variants['QUAL'][:]
    vq = variants['VQSLOD'][:]
    numalt = variants['numalt'][:]
    csq = variants['CSQ'][:]
    vcfv = 'VCFv4.1'
    refv = 'file:///lustre/scratch105/projects/g1k/ref/main_project/human_g1k_v37.fasta'
    dpz = callset[chrom]['calldata/DP']
    psz = callset[chrom]['calldata/PS']
    plz = callset[chrom]['calldata/PL']
    gpz = callset[chrom]['calldata/GP']
    calldata = callset[chrom]['calldata']
    gt = allel.GenotypeDaskArray(calldata['GT'])
    hap = gt.to_haplotypes()
    hap1 = hap[:, ::2]
    hap2 = hap[:, 1::2]
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(samples)):
        subject = samples[i]
        subject_node = matcher.match("Subject", subject_id= subject)
        if subject_node.first() is None:
            continue
        seq_tech = 'Illumina HiSeq 2000 (ILLUMINA)'
        dp = dpz[:, i]
        ps = psz[:, i]
        pl = plz[:, i]
        gp = gpz[:, i]
        list_h1 = hap1[:, i].compute()
        list_h2 = hap2[:, i].compute()
        chrom_label = "Chromosome_" + str(chrom)
        j = 0
        for j in range(len(pos)):  
            h1 = int(list_h1[j])
            h2 = int(list_h2[j])
            read_depth = int(dp[j])
            ps1 = int(ps[j])
            PL0 = int(pl[j][0])
            PL1 = int(pl[j][1])
            PL2 = int(pl[j][2])
            genotype = str(h1) + '|' + str(h2)
            GP0 = float(gp[j][0])
            GP1 = float(gp[j][1])
            GP2 = float(gp[j][2])
            k = int(pos[j])
            l = str(ref[j])
            m = str(alt[j][h1-1])
            o = str(alt[j][h2-1])

            if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                a1 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = l)
                r2 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Homozygous", a1.first(), HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r2)

            elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:
                a1 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = l)
                r2 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Heterozygous", a1.first(), HTA=h1, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r2)
                a2 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = o)
                r3 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Heterozygous", a2.first(), HTB=h2, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r3)

            elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                a1 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = m)
                r2 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Heterozygous", a1.first(), HTA=h1, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r2)
                a2 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = l)
                r3 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Heterozygous", a2.first(), HTB=h2, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r3)

            elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                a1 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = m)
                r2 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Homozygous", a1.first(), HTA = h1, HTB = h2, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r2)

            else:
                a1 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = m)
                r2 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Heterozygous", a1.first(), HTA=h1, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r2)

                a2 = matcher.match(chrom_label, "Allele", pos= k, bp = o)
                r3 = Relationship(subject_node.first(), "Heterozygous", a2.first(), HTB=h2, GT=genotype, seq_tech=seq_tech, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                graph.create(r3)
        print("Subject " + subject + " completed.")
print(chrom_label + "completed.")
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a lot of elements individually will always be slow, largely because of the number of network hops required. You're also carrying out matches in between each as well, which will further increase the time.

The best approach to this kind of problem is to look at batching, both for reads and for writes. While you can't do everything at once either, batching your operations into at least a few hundred at a time will have a significant effect. In your case, you will probably need to carry out a bulk read, followed by a bulk write, and so on.

So specifically, look to carry out a match against multiple entities (you might be able to use an "in" modifier for this, or you might need to drop into raw Cypher). For writes, build up a subgraph locally with the relevant nodes and relationships and create that in a single call.

Your optimal batch size will only be discovered through experimentation, so you likely won't get this right first time. But batching is definitely the key here.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll just have to get my brain around the best way to go about this!