# Py2Neo Issue with Batch Transactions - AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python, neo4j, transactions, py2neo

Following asking [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058437/transcribing-large-datasets-into-neo4j-via-python-py2neo), I've tried to use batch transactions with Py2Neo to speed things up.  I've adapted my code quite a bit, but seem unable to build and execute a batch of transactions.  The matching works fine, it's only the transaction piece at the bottom which I'm having issues with - I thought I would include my entire code, just in case though.  The current error I'm getting is as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-953d29f58a36> in <module>
    108                 a = nodes[x]
    109                 print(a)
--> 110                 tx.run(a)
    111                 rela = Relationship(s, "HOMOZYGOUS", a, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
    112                 print(rela)

~/anaconda3/envs/genome/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/database.py in run(self, cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    803                                              graph=self.graph,
    804                                              keys=[],
--> 805                                              entities=entities))
    806         except CypherError as error:
    807             raise GraphError.hydrate({"code": error.code, "message": error.message})

~/anaconda3/envs/genome/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/internal/connectors.py in run(self, statement, parameters, tx, graph, keys, entities)
    285             return self._run_1(statement, parameters, graph, keys, entities)
    286         else:
--> 287             return self._run_in_tx(statement, parameters, tx, graph, keys, entities)
    288 
    289     def begin(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/genome/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/internal/connectors.py in _run_in_tx(self, statement, parameters, tx, graph, keys, entities)
    269             hydrator.keys = result.keys()
    270 
--> 271         tx.run(statement, dehydrated_parameters or {}, on_success=update_metadata_with_keys, on_failure=fail)
    272         tx.pull_all(on_records=lambda records: result.append_records(map(hydrator.hydrate, records)),
    273                     on_success=result.update_metadata, on_failure=fail, on_summary=result.done)

~/anaconda3/envs/genome/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py in run(self, statement, parameters, mode, bookmarks, metadata, timeout, **handlers)
    292             fields = (statement, parameters)
    293         log_debug("[#%04X]  C: RUN %s", self.local_port, " ".join(map(repr, fields)))
--> 294         if statement.upper() == u"COMMIT":
    295             self._append(b"\x10", fields, CommitResponse(self, **handlers))
    296         else:

AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import math
import allel
import zarr
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, NodeMatcher
zarr_path = 'filepath'
callset = zarr.open_group(zarr_path, mode='r')
graph = Graph(user="neo4j", password="password")
chrom_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,'X']
matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)
for chrom in chrom_list:
    chrom_label = "Chromosome_" + str(chrom)
    samples = callset[chrom]['samples']
    variants = allel.VariantChunkedTable(callset[chrom]['variants'], names=['AC','AF_AFR', 'AF_AMR', 'AF_ASN', 'AF_EUR', 'AF_MAX', 'CGT', 'CLR', 'CSQ', 'DP', 'DP4', 'ESP_MAF', 'FILTER_LowQual', 'FILTER_MinHWE', 'FILTER_MinVQSLOD', 'FILTER_PASS', 'HWE', 'ICF', 'ID', 'IS', 'PC2', 'PCHI2', 'POS', 'PR', 'QCHI2', 'QUAL', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INDEL', 'SHAPEIT', 'SNP_ID', 'TYPE', 'UGT', 'VQSLOD', 'dbSNPmismatch', 'is_snp', 'numalt'], index='POS')
    pos = variants['POS'][:]
    pos = pos.tolist()
    ref = variants['REF'][:]
    alt = variants['ALT'][:]
    dpz = callset[chrom]['calldata/DP']
    dp = dpz[:, 0]
    psz = callset[chrom]['calldata/PS']
    plz = callset[chrom]['calldata/PL']
    gpz = callset[chrom]['calldata/GP']
    calldata = callset[chrom]['calldata']
    gt = allel.GenotypeDaskArray(calldata['GT'])
    hap = gt.to_haplotypes()
    hap = gt.to_haplotypes()
    hap1 = hap[:, ::2]
    hap2 = hap[:, 1::2]
    list_h1 = hap1[:, 0].compute()
    list_h1 = list_h1.tolist()
    list_h2 = hap2[:, 0].compute()
    for i in range(len(samples)):
        subject = samples[i]
        dp = dpz[:, i]
        ps = psz[:, i]
        pl = plz[:, i]
        gp = gpz[:, i]
        list_h1 = hap1[:, i].compute()
        list_h2 = hap2[:, i].compute()
        g = Graph()
        tx = g.begin()
        print(subject)
        s = matcher.match("Subject", subject_id= subject).first()
        print(s)
        if s is None:
            continue
        j = 0
        nodes = []
        for j in range(len(pos)):
            h1 = int(list_h1[j])
            h2 = int(list_h2[j])
            k = int(pos[j])
            l = str(ref[j])
            m = str(alt[j][h1-1])
            o = str(alt[j][h2-1])
            if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=l).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                nodes.append(a)
            elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=l).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=o).first()
                nodes.append(a)

            elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=m).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=l).first()
                nodes.append(a)

            elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=m).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                nodes.append(a)

            else:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=m).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=o).first()
                nodes.append(a)
            if j % 1000 == 0:
                print(str(j) + " rows complete.")
        print(subject + " matching complete.")
        print(len(nodes))
        j=0
        for j in range(len(pos)):
            read_depth = int(dp[j])
            ps1 = int(ps[j])
            PL0 = int(pl[j][0])
            PL1 = int(pl[j][1])
            PL2 = int(pl[j][2])
            genotype = str(h1) + '|' + str(h2) 
            GP0 = float(gp[j][0])
            GP1 = float(gp[j][1])
            GP2 = float(gp[j][2])
            h1 = int(list_h1[j])
            h2 = int(list_h2[j])
            k = int(pos[j])
            l = str(ref[j])
            m = str(alt[j][h1-1])
            o = str(alt[j][h2-1])
            if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                x = (2*j)
                print(x)
                a = nodes[x]
                print(a)
                tx.run(a)
                rela = Relationship(s, "HOMOZYGOUS", a, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                print(rela)
                tx.run(rela)

            elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[x]
                tx.run(a)
                rela = Relationship(s, "HETEROZYGOUS", a, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(rela)
                y = (2*j)+1
                b = nodes[y]
                tx.run(b)
                relb = Relationship(s, "HETEROZYGOUS", b, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(relb)

            elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[j]
                tx.run(a)
                rela = Relationship(s, "HETEROZYGOUS", a, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(rela)
                y = (2*j)+1
                b = nodes[y]
                tx.run(b)
                relb = Relationship(s, "HETEROZYGOUS", b, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(relb)

            elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[j]
                tx.run(a)
                rela = Relationship(s, "HOMOZYGOUS", a, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(rela)
            else:
                x = (2*j)
                a = node[j]
                tx.run(a)
                rela = Relationship(s, "HETEROZYGOUS", a, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(rela)
                y = (2*j)+1
                b = nodes[y]
                tx.run(b)
                relb = Relationship(s, "HETEROZYGOUS", b, HTA=h1, HTB=h2, GT=genotype, dp=read_depth, phase_set=ps1, PL0=PL0, PL1=PL1, PL2=PL2, GP0=GP0, GP1=GP1, GP2=GP2)
                tx.run(relb)
            if j % 1000 == 0:
                tx.commit()
            
    print(chrom_label + " completed.")
```

I'm adding the nodes as objects into the query, but this prints out fine: e.g. it returns:

```
(_0:Allele:Chromosome_1:Reference {SNPid: 'rs147999235', bp: 'T', pos: 738539})
```

for a node, and:

```
(_971387)-[:HOMOZYGOUS {GP0: 1.0, GP1: 0.0, GP2: 0.0, GT: '0|0', HTA: 0, HTB: 0, PL0: 0, PL1: 21, PL2: 166, dp: 7, phase_set: 28590}]->(_0)
```

for a relationship, as it should.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from attempting to "run" Node and Relationship objects. The `tx.run` method takes a Cypher string as its first argument, so lines like `tx.run(a)` don't make semantic sense.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve changed it all around to Cypher queries now and it seems to work.