# Py2neo script stops ~90s after successfully committing transactions

Tags: python, neo4j, transactions, py2neo

After changing the code in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152233/py2neo-issue-with-batch-transactions-attributeerror-node-object-has-no-attr) to build cypher transactions instead of creating nodes and relationships in Py2neo, it seems to work successfully, but transactions stop after about 90 seconds, with no error message.  The script continues to run, but the iterations stop and no further transactions are made, and looking at the logs it appears all interaction with the database stops. Can anyone help me understand why this might be?  The following code is being executed from Jupyter.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import math
import allel
import zarr
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, NodeMatcher

zarr_path = '/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_twin_cohort/exome/chroms.zarr'
callset = zarr.open_group(zarr_path, mode='r')

graph = Graph(user="neo4j", password="password")

chrom_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,'X']
matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)

for chrom in chrom_list:
    chrom_label = "Chromosome_" + str(chrom)
    samples = callset[chrom]['samples']
    variants = allel.VariantChunkedTable(callset[chrom]['variants'], names=['AC','AF_AFR', 'AF_AMR', 'AF_ASN', 'AF_EUR', 'AF_MAX', 'CGT', 'CLR', 'CSQ', 'DP', 'DP4', 'ESP_MAF', 'FILTER_LowQual', 'FILTER_MinHWE', 'FILTER_MinVQSLOD', 'FILTER_PASS', 'HWE', 'ICF', 'ID', 'IS', 'PC2', 'PCHI2', 'POS', 'PR', 'QCHI2', 'QUAL', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INDEL', 'SHAPEIT', 'SNP_ID', 'TYPE', 'UGT', 'VQSLOD', 'dbSNPmismatch', 'is_snp', 'numalt'], index='POS')
    pos = variants['POS'][:]
    pos = pos.tolist()
    ref = variants['REF'][:]
    alt = variants['ALT'][:]
    dpz = callset[chrom]['calldata/DP']
    dp = dpz[:, 0]
    psz = callset[chrom]['calldata/PS']
    plz = callset[chrom]['calldata/PL']
    gpz = callset[chrom]['calldata/GP']
    calldata = callset[chrom]['calldata']
    gt = allel.GenotypeDaskArray(calldata['GT'])
    hap = gt.to_haplotypes()
    hap = gt.to_haplotypes()
    hap1 = hap[:, ::2]
    hap2 = hap[:, 1::2]
    list_h1 = hap1[:, 0].compute()
    list_h1 = list_h1.tolist()
    list_h2 = hap2[:, 0].compute()
    for i in range(len(samples)):
        subject = samples[i]
        dp = dpz[:, i]
        ps = psz[:, i]
        pl = plz[:, i]
        gp = gpz[:, i]
        list_h1 = hap1[:, i].compute()
        list_h2 = hap2[:, i].compute()
        bp1 = []
        bp2 = []
        hpt = []
        n1 = []
        n2 = []
        g = Graph()
        print(subject)
        print("Subject " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(samples)))
        s = matcher.match("Subject", subject_id= subject).first()
        print(s)
        if s is None:
            continue
        j = 0
        nodes = []
        for j in range(len(pos)):
            h1 = int(list_h1[j])
            h2 = int(list_h2[j])
            k = int(pos[j])
            l = str(ref[j])
            m = str(alt[j][h1-1])
            o = str(alt[j][h2-1])
            if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=l).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                nodes.append(a)

            elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=l).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=o).first()
                nodes.append(a)

            elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=m).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=l).first()
                nodes.append(a)

            elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=m).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                nodes.append(a)

            else:
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=m).first()
                nodes.append(a)
                a = matcher.match(chrom_label, pos=k, bp=o).first()
                nodes.append(a)
            if j % 10000 == 0:
                print(str(j) + " rows complete.")
        print(subject + " matching complete.")
        print(len(nodes))
        j=0
        tx = g.begin()
        for j in range(len(pos)):
            read_depth = int(dp[j])
            ps1 = int(ps[j])
            PL0 = int(pl[j][0])
            PL1 = int(pl[j][1])
            PL2 = int(pl[j][2])
            genotype = str(h1) + '|' + str(h2) 
            GP0 = float(gp[j][0])
            GP1 = float(gp[j][1])
            GP2 = float(gp[j][2])
            h1 = int(list_h1[j])
            h2 = int(list_h2[j])
            k = int(pos[j])
            l = str(ref[j])
            m = str(alt[j][h1-1])
            o = str(alt[j][h2-1])

            if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[x]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {A} MERGE (s)-[r:HOMOZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "A":a.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
            elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[x]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {A} MERGE (s)-[r:HETEROZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "A":a.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
                y = (2*j)+1
                b = nodes[y]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {B} MERGE (s)-[r:HETEROZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "B":b.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
            elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[j]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {A} MERGE (s)-[r:HETEROZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "A":a.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
                y = (2*j)+1
                b = nodes[y]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {B} MERGE (s)-[r:HETEROZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "B":b.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
            elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[j]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {A} MERGE (s)-[r:HOMOZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "A":a.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
            else:
                x = (2*j)
                a = nodes[j]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {A} MERGE (s)-[r:HETEROZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "A":a.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
                y = (2*j)+1
                b = nodes[y]
                tx.run("MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {S} MATCH (a) WHERE id(a) = {B} MERGE (s)-[r:HETEROZYGOUS {HTA:{H1}, HTB:{H2}, GT:{GT}, dp:{DP}, phase_set:{PS1}, PL0:{PL0}, PL1:{PL1}, PL2:{PL2}, GP0:{GP0}, GP1:{GP1}, GP2:{GP2}}]->(a)", {"S":s.identity, "B":b.identity, "H1":h1, "H2":h2, "GT":genotype, "DP":read_depth, "PS1":ps1, "PL0":PL0, "PL1":PL1, "PL2":PL2, "GP0":GP0, "GP1":GP1, "GP2":GP2 })
            if j % 1000 == 0:
                print(str(j) + " rows added to database.")
                tx.commit()
                tx = g.begin()

    print(chrom_label + " completed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You only call `tx.commit()` when the `j % 1000 == 0` test succeeds. You need to make sure you call `tx.commit()` if necessary after  you exit the `j` for-loop, else the last batch of operations will be dropped.

*By the way, you are currently calling `tx.commit()` the first time through the loop (since `0 % 1000 == 0`). You probably want to avoid that.*

Comment: Will it make a difference if the first j iteration commits on it’s own? Thanks, I’ll give it a try and see what happens. I’m still not sure it explains the way the script just stops though. I’m starting to think it might be a Jupyter issue.

Comment: Committing the first time is inefficient, but should not cause your main issue. And you could just change the test to `if (j+1) % 1000 == 0` to avoid it.